# Terminating all unnecessary processes using a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

As a security precaution, I would like a way where I can force terminate all processes that are not required for the Windows operating system to operate. I additionally want to make sure that no new process starts, and print all terminated processes so I know where to look. 
This is so that in case I accidentally download malware and it is still in its early stages, I can possibly revert possible damages and more easily remove the source. 
I do not know how to approach this issue, and thus I seek help with my own question. Thank you in advance :)

PS: If there can be a way to provide an exit button to the batch script that would be great, but not necessary! :)

Comment: Are you really asking for an on-demand purely Windows built-in batch file antimalware solution?

Comment: Not precisely. What I'm looking for is just a way to suppress all unnecessary processes. So basically I'm looking for an alternative to safe mode, only minus the hassle of rebooting.

Comment: Sorry, so you want an on-demand purely Windows built-in batch file task manager solution instead?

Comment: in a sense... but the point of it is so that it is a one-click process safe mode

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read through [these links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After having done so, you should consider a major edit of the above, or pressing on the delete option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `tasklist` and `taskkill`.

Make a list of safe programs, and crosscheck it against every task currently running, killing it if it isn't on the list.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set safeArray="system idle process" "system" "registry" "svchost.exe" & rem etc

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in ('tasklist /fo csv /nh') do (
    set tmp=0
    for /f %%k in ('echo %safeArray% ^| find /i /c "%%~i"') do set /a tmp+=%%k
    if !tmp! lss 1 echo I want to taskkill - %%~i  PID: %%~j
)

pause
```

I've left the actual killing out of the script right now as you will want to set up you safe array first. 
Replace `echo I want to taskkill…` line with `taskkill /pid %%~j`.

Comment: Also note that you will probably want to avoid the process killing itself before finishing.